# Bringing gifts when visiting office HQ

Tags: united-states, telecommute, gifts

I'm a remote (foreign) employee who works for a US company. I frequently visit the HQ, and while I've never really given gifts in the past, I really want to catch up on birthdays/wedding gifts/etc, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to deal with this.

I won't be able to buy gifts to everyone  in there, so I'd like to buy something for the people I'm closest with. Would this be weird? Should I give these gifts in a very discreet manner? Or should I skip this idea and just bring some chocolates for the whole office?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A communal gift is a good idea. Since you mentioned you are a foreign employee, a local sweet/delicacy could be a better idea than chocolate.

As long as you have a communal gift, giving individual gifts to those you are close to/work with most shouldn't be frowned upon by others. Whether to give it discretely or in public is totally up to your preferences.

Comment: This one is more in line with my own experience as a foreign employee visiting the US home office, and also with having people from the home office visiting us. We would always get a communal gift, and the individual gifts for the ones we're closest to. Since there was sort of a regular routine for visits, we would also smuggle things back and forth on order ("Hey, I'm visiting you next month, do you want something?")

Answer (score 5):

I would go with a communal box of chocolates or a local (to you) equivalent if relevant.

Trying to explain why you did some and not others with individual gifts may well be challenging so a communal gift is likely to be the best option.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! Do you think adding a small gift for some individuals as well as the communal box of chocolate will be okay?

Comment: Your comment is addressed in my second paragraph...

Comment: My experience in the same position (foreign employee visiting the home office) is that it is totally OK to give small individual gifts for the ones you have more proximity with if you go for the communal gift too. Example: bring a box of sweets / snacks from your place and a small individual gift for the other ones you're trying to catch up on (small decoration for who moved in, I gave handmade baby booties for one that was expecting a baby girl). The reverse also happened, my boss (american) was visiting us and he brought in a communal box of chocolates and another smaller box for me

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza I have brought tea bags (pg tips or yorkshire...) marmite and many other things on demand for particular colleagues, and that is why I put « may well be challenging » and «  likely to be the best option », however there are often exceptions for you to work out in your particular situation... I tried to put a general answer, but if you have particular colleagues with which you have a strong bond then that is an individual situation.